# Cannot Resolve Symbol: FusedLocationProviderClient. Google play services version used 11.0.1

Tags: android, google-play-services

> Cannot Resolve Symbol: FusedLocationProviderClient.

Google play services version used 11.0.1.

code : while declaration

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mfusedLocationProviderclient;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code,  the outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: Typically your posts on a Q&A site should  include an actual question. Adding code helps too. Like your Gradle files

Comment: If it can't resolve in the field, then you did not import the class.

Comment: I did and the issue is resolved. This location services update is available in the latest android studio version(2.3.3)

Answer (score 145):

You just need to include this in your **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

or if you're not using latest gradle version:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
```

Note: It's recommended to use Google Play services version `15.0.1` or higher, which includes bug fixes for this class. More details here.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

Comment: You also need to add the line `import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;` to your Activity.

Comment: to get the latest version of the dependency:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 11):

In your `build.gradle` (Module: app), you need to add the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
}
```

and rebuild your app so it can download the needed dependencies. The class `FusedLocationProviderClient` is included in this package.

Comment: It's not working for me. What all other features be there to resolve this?

Comment: Look answer below and read the docs, use specific library you need so you don't bloat your app with stuff you don't use.

Answer (score 9):

Import following lines to the code after you have changed the `build.gradle(Mudule:app)` including implementation:

```
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

Comment: Could you please highlight what is code and what not with the provided tool of SO-editor!

Answer (score 6):

You just need to include this in your build.gradle file:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'

Code for retrieve Location :

```
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient =  LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 6):

In build.gradle (Module: app) add:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
   ...
}
```

Don't forget to sync the `build.gradle` (on the up right corner of the `build.gradle`, you will have a notification to sync the changes, click it).

Answer (score 5):

This Developer [Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) solved my problem

Comment: I wonder why the docs don't point us to the right place to get the required dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I should include

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0
```

Not just `play-services-maps:11.4.0.`

Answer (score 2):

Add `COARSE_PERMISSION` in `manifest.xml` file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`
then it automatic detects the `Class` and imports it.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very late, but happy to answer the question.

Use this dependencies

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'

and refer this link - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include this in your build.gradle file:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'`

version of the services for location and maps should be the same.

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'`

Answer (score 0):

update your google play services to 11.8.0
The code that should be added to the bulild file is as follows

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'`

Answer (score 0):

As everyone replied you need to put into your build.gradle file the line :

```
implement 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
```

(substituting `implement` for `compile` depending on your gradle version)
The version just needs to be above 11.0.1, apparently.

However, when I did this I had a new error. Since I was already implementing the Play Service libraries (analytics, auth, maps, location) in a previous version (10.0.1) I had to change these all to the new version - you cant have only one of the libraries at a different version, need to have them all matching.
So I found the implement lines with these libraries and changed them to:

```
implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-analytics', version: '11.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-auth', version: '11.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-maps', version: '11.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-location', version: '11.0.1'
```

Since I was also implementing firebase (not even sure what this is for and why it is related to Play Services), I had to the similar thing:

```
implementation group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-core', version: '11.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-crash', version: '11.0.1'
```

Sync your project with gradle files and your `FusedLocationProviderClient` should be visible/available, starting at the import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
```