# Cannot resolve symbol 'FusedLocationProviderClient'

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I having a error**Cannot resolve symbol 'FusedLocationProviderClient'** while declaring

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
```

[image: Here is snapshot of my gradle file.]

The same is asked here [Cannot Resolve Symbol: FusedLocationProviderClient. Google play services version used 11.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651889/cannot-resolve-symbol-fusedlocationproviderclient-google-play-services-version) . But still am having the error while using the latest play services.

Comment: Post code here, please!

Comment: Please look at the compile version carefully, you are using maps service and they tell u to use play service

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FusedLocationProvider is part of play-services-location. You are using play-services-maps. Add dependency :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

**Edit**

Seems like this was helpful for quite a few people. Here is a link to google docs where all individual library names in play-services along with latest version numbers are kept : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup I hope google keeps it updated.

Note: It's recommended to use Google Play services version 11.6.0 or higher, which includes bug fixes for this class. More details here.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient