# FusedLocationProviderClient could not be found in Google Play Services

Tags: android, xamarin, google-api, google-play-services, google-location-services

I am trying to use Location Service of Google Play Services with Xamarin by following this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location

**IsGooglePlayServicesInstalled** function returns true, and **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps** is installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does the error log say pls print it

Comment: It looks like I am missing package or namespace.. the error is:
The type or namespace name 'FusedLocationProviderClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you show the play service version which you are using

Comment: Version: 12.2.21 (448-188803320)

Comment: I'v already mentioned in the post that I am following this link. I followed the steps but cant define the FusedLocationProviderClient.
I don't think the version of my google play services matter, because the build fails when I add the definition of FusedLocationProviderClient instance.

Comment: Please provide build/runtime errors

Comment: its not error, simply I cant reach the 'FusedLocationProviderClient' class,
Although I installed  the Maps package and included the namespaces as the article explained.

Comment: Look at this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651889/cannot-resolve-symbol-fusedlocationproviderclient-google-play-services-version/44829527

In android studio to fix this issue, we need to include dependency in build.gradle file, is it the same situation in Xamarin ? and what is the alternative for this file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The solution is: Install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location nuget package.**

In the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location), they didn't mention this package, I even didn't know that it exists.