# get error when i tried to use FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, location

i tried to make an android app getting my current location but i can't figure out why it doesn't work FusedLocationProviderClient

```
package com.example.mainactivity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FusedLocationProviderClient client;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

and yes, i added compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'

Comment: Share more code and have you add permission related code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44651889/cannot-resolve-symbol-fusedlocationproviderclient-google-play-services-version#answer-44829527  Note: It's recommended to use Google Play services version 11.6.0 or higher, which includes bug fixes for this class.

Comment: what permission?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran it's not working with 15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: Could not find com.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/gms/play-services/11.0.1/play-services-11.0.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/gms/play-services/11.0.1/play-services-11.0.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/gms/play-services/11.0.1/play-services-11.0.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/gms/play-services/11.0.1/play-services-11.0.1.jar
Required by:
    project :

When i code FusedLocation... it s not showing me FusedLocationProviderLocation and if i code manually shows Cannot resolve symbol 'FusedLocationProviderClient

Answer (score 0):

Try https://medium.com/@ssaurel/getting-gps-location-on-android-with-fused-location-provider-api-1001eb549089. It has mentioned steps in detail. 
If you google you will get multiple blogs on using FusedLocation API.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in manifest.xml

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`
>
> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Ask for the permissions if not granted, see [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/get-current-location-using-fusedlocationproviderclient-in-android-cb7ebf5ab88e)